# Do I always need two NIC's in order to install VPN on my server?

Tags: vpn

I am watching some video guide on how to setup a VPN Server and he says you need two network cards (one internal, one external). I only have one right now, is there any way around this?

Edit:  I am  using a test environment where my domain is on windows 2008 R2 and now I want to test for another user to reach my domain on another network through VPN.

Comment: It completely depends on how you what to setup your network and VPN.  There are several potentially useful situations where you could have a single network interface.  Can you update your question to tell us what you are trying to accomplish with this VPN?

Comment: Please consider revisiting some of your questions.  Mark things as accepted if you have received a useful answer, or add comments or revise your questions with any additional details so we can get more of your questions resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *might* depend on the VPN server software you're using, but usually no, a VPN server can work with a single NIC, as long as you can make it accessible from outside your network through your firewall. This is certainly the case for Windows' RRAS.

Comment: If Massimo answered your question, please can you click on the grey tick to the left?

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN server makes virtual interface with their own subnet, so you don't need two NICs.

Comment: I updated the first post.